# Connect to Postgres DB RDS from Amazon EC2 using psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, psycopg2

I am trying to connect to Postgres RDS from Amazon EC2 Linux. Python 2.6 is already installed but I need to install psycopg2 and python3.6 as psycopg2 isn't compatible with python2.6 I would need commands to install that.

Post python3.6 and psycopg2 is installed, will below script give the output or does it need any fix?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import psycopg2
conn_string="dbname='abc' port='5432' user='admin' password='admin' host='xyz.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com'"
conn=psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
cursor=conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('select version()')
conn.commit()
cursor.close()
print("working")
```

Comment: It won't make a difference to the correctness of your code, but you don't need the `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` comment at the top of your program in Python 3. That is the default.

Comment: I tried to run the script without that but as it was giving some ASCII errors, I had to include that. Post inclusion of that line, the error disappeared.

Comment: Have you tried to run it? Did it give an error?

Comment: Yes. It wasn't able to import psycopg2.